# Intellij plugin: get stored procedure from database

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I'm working on an Intellij (all products: phpStorm, Rider, Idea, etc) plugin to generate code from a data source (database tool window).

I get the needed data like this:

```
// Get all data sources
ProjectManager pm = ProjectManager.getInstance();
Project[] projects = pm.getOpenProjects();
Arrays.stream(projects).map(project ->
       DbPsiFacade.getInstance(project).getDataSources())
       .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Get Tables
DasUtil.getTables(source);
// Get columns
DasUtil.getColumns(table);
```

But I did not find any way to get a list of DbRoutine, which seems to represent the stored procedure.

Anyone knows how to get it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it using a different method:

```
DbDataSource dataSource = ...;
dataSource.getModel().traverser().forEach(dasObject ->
    {
        if (dasObject instanceof DasTable) {
        }
        else if (dasObject instanceof DasColumn) {
        }
        else if (dasObject instanceof DasIndex) {
        }
        else if (dasObject instanceof DasConstraint) {
        }
        else if (dasObject instanceof DasRoutine) {
        }
    });
```